# R for or next loop on XLConnect readworksheetfromfile

Tags: r, loops, xlconnect

Please can someone explain how I can do a loop on xlconnect based on whether a excel sheet exists across multiple files. I have looked on
[How to write the first for loop](https://www.r-bloggers.com/how-to-write-the-first-for-loop-in-r/) but I can't work it out for what I am trying to do.
 Example: If I have 5 excel files some with sheet1 and some with sheet1 and sheet2 how can I say if the file has sheet2 then readworksheet else skip to next file.

```
filenames<-list.files(location,pattern='xlsx',full.names = TRUE)#this gives the file path of all files
data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
  wb = loadWorkbook(f)
  existsSheet(filenames, "sheet2") 
})# this thows an error because it can't find the sheet from file
```

I think I need something like the below but to handle the error so that if there is no sheet2 then go to readworksheet from the next file.

```
for (file in filenames) {
  newFile = readWorksheetFromFile(file=file, sheet="sheet2")
  df = merge(newFile, newFile, all=TRUE)
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `existsSheet(wb, "sheet2")`?

Comment: Thank you yes it should be `existsSheet(wb, "sheet2")`  
but I am still not sure how I can read these files into 1 dataframe. I am trying the following but the if statement doesnt work. 

`newdf=if(
  data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
    wb = loadWorkbook(f)
    existsSheet(wb, "sheet2")
  }) ==TRUE)
{list.files(location, pattern="xlsx")} # this will give a list of files with sheet2
df.list = lapply(newdf, function(i) {
  readWorksheetFromFile(paste0(folder, i), sheet="sheet2")
}) #this will read all the sheets
sheet2 <- do.call(rbind, df.list)#this merges sheets together`

Comment: `data` is a logical vector, so `filenames[data]` will be the vector of filesnames with a "sheet2".  So `wbList <- lapply(filenames[data],readWorksheetFromFile,sheet="sheet2")` will read these in and save them as a list of dataframes.  You can join them together with `do.call(rbind,wbList)`

Comment: Sorry it should be this but still not working which makes me think i need a for loop`Data = lapply(filenames, function(f) {
  wb = loadWorkbook(f)
if(existsSheet(wb, "sheet2")==TRUE)(list.files(location, pattern="xlsx"))
}) ` This still pulls out all file names instead of just the sheet2

Comment: Thanks Andrew but using I get the following error "Error in filenames[data] : invalid subscript type 'list'"

Comment: Ah - yes - just change `lapply` to `sapply` in your calculation of `data` - that will output it as a vector rather than a list.  Or you can use `unlist(data)`.

Comment: Thank you this worked perfectly :)